# Jquery: Replace all unformatted text outside of html tags with multiple dropdown boxes

Tags: javascript, html, regex, drop-down-menu, replace

I wish to find a substring (from an array) within a string, then replace it with a dropdown box which will have title equal to the substring.

The string is from user input, the substrings having been drawn from a database in my working code.

I have worked from the answer given by DavidTonarini in this question: [Javascript: replace() all but only outside html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26951003/javascript-replace-all-but-only-outside-html-tags)

However, this only excludes the text which is contained between '<' and '<'.

I have also used jconder's answer to this question. This has partially solved the problem.

If you input: 'a levels a level' into the working fiddle included, then you will see that 'a levels' is returned as a dropdown box, but 'a level' is returned as plain text, nbut it is supposed to be matched with its entry in the array and replaced with a dropdown box. Problems also occur when repeating the same string within the user input. I would like the ability to match the same substring multiple times within a user input.

```js
var data = {
  "a_levels": {
    "a_level": {
      id: 1,
      units: 2,
      created: "2016-10-04 19:00:05",
      updated: "2016-10-05 09:37:46"
    },
    "a_levels": {
      id: 2,
      units: 2,
      created: "2016-10-05 08:19:27",
      updated: "2016-10-05 09:37:39"
    }
  },
  "a_level": {
    "a_level": {
      id: 1,
      units: 2,
      created: "2016-10-04 19:00:05",
      updated: "2016-10-05 09:37:46"
    },
    "a_levels": {
      id: 2,
      units: 2,
      created: "2016-10-05 08:19:27",
      updated: "2016-10-05 09:37:39"
    }
  }
};
var input, // Create empty variables.
  response;

$('#submit').click(function() {
  input = $('#userInput').val();
  response = input;
  // CREATE DROPDOWN BOXES.
  var strings_used = [];
  $.each(data, function(i, v) { // Iterate over first level of output.

    for (var itr = 0; itr < strings_used.length; ++itr) {
      if (strings_used[itr].indexOf(i) !== -1) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    var searchWord = i.replace(/_/g, " "); // Replace underscores in matches with blank spaces.
    var regEx = new RegExp("(" + searchWord + ")(?!([^<]+)?>)", "gi"); // Create regular expression which searches only for matches found outside html tags.
    var tmp = response.replace(regEx, "<span class='btn-group'><button class='btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle' type='button' data-toggle='dropdown'>" + searchWord + "<span class='caret'></span></button><ul class='" + i + " dropdown-menu'></ul></span>"); // Replace matching substrings with dropdown boxes.
    if (tmp !== response) { // Check if replacement is complete.
      response = tmp; // Update response.
      strings_used.push(i);
    }
  });
  $('#template').empty().append(response); // Populate template container with completed question response including dropdown boxes.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div id="searchbox">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input id="userInput" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="type here...">
      <span id="submit" class="input-group-btn">
     <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">GO!</button>
   </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div id="template" class="col-sm-10 col-md-offset-1 text-left"></div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: the first argument from [jquery each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) is the index. use the second argument! `var searchWord = i.replace(/_/g, " ");` to `var searchWord = v.replace(/_/g, " ");`

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. 'output' is actually a JSON object, the first layer of which contains the entries listed in the array. I just changed it for simplicity, as this code does not need to access any further layers. I will update the question for clarity. Thanks!

Comment: What you are asking doesn't seem to make sense.  In the first result, the text is within a tag.  In the second result, the text is within a tag, that is also within the same original tag.  What is the difference?  Or maybe better, if you would remove all of the extra details from the question it might make what you want clear.

Comment: To put it simply, the code should run twice - once for each array member - and should ignore all text once it has been placed in tags. The code should create tags during the first iteration. The code should do nothing during the second iteration, because the text is already within tags. However, as you can see from the console information, a second set of tags is created within the first.

Comment: So to be clear, you only care if it is inside of a span tag, not if it is inside of an arbitrary tag?

Comment: I will try another example:

if the array = [ 'found abandoned', 'totally'], then if string = 'the car was found abandoned', the text inside square brackets is replaced = 'the car was [found abandoned]'. If string = 'the car was found totally abandoned', then replaced text = 'the car was found [totally] abandoned'. However, if array = ['car was found totally abandoned', 'found totally abandoned', 'totally'], then if string = 'the car was found totally abandoned', we get 'the [car was [found [totally] abandoned] ]', but we want 'the [car was found totally abandoned]'.

Comment: It is likely that this formatting is all that will ever be applied to the string, so if it has to be specific to this code then it shouldn't pose any issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly now, you want it to stop iterating through the dictionary after the first substitution is made.  In that case, this should work:

```
var output = ['the_car_was_found_abandoned_in_a_nearby_town', 'found_abandoned'];
var template = 'the car was found abandoned in a nearby town';

$.each(output, function(i,v){
  var searchWord = v.replace(/_/g, " ");
  var regEx = new RegExp("("+searchWord+")(?!([^<]+)?>)", "gi");

  var tmp = template.replace(regEx, "<span class='btn-group'><button class='btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle' type='button' data-toggle='dropdown'>"+searchWord+"<span class='caret'></span></button><ul id='"+i+"' class='dropdown-menu'></ul></span>");
  if (tmp !== template) {
    template = tmp;
    console.log(template);
    return false;
  }
});
```

By checking if the regex modified the string, you can detect if a substitution was made, and then by `returning false;` from the `$.each()` callback you can end the iterations early.

Although I'm not sure this if the entire picture, if you instead only want it to skip other entries in the dictionary that are substrings of a longer, better fitting match, then you'll need to order the dictionary in a slightly different way, such as this:

```
var dict = {
    "the_car_was_found_abandoned_in_a_nearby_town":
      ["the_car_was_found_abandoned_in_a_nearby_town", "found_abandoned"],
    "some_other_text_that_isn't_a_substring_of_another_entry:
      ["some_other_text_that_isn't_a_substring_of_another_entry", "of_another_entry", "some_other"]
};
```

If you order the dictionary that way, then you could run the above algorithm like this:

```
var dict = {
    "the_car_was_found_abandoned_in_a_nearby_town":
      ["the_car_was_found_abandoned_in_a_nearby_town", "found_abandoned"],
    "some_other_text_that_isn't_a_substring_of_another_entry:
      ["some_other_text_that_isn't_a_substring_of_another_entry", "of_another_entry", "some_other"]
};
var template = 'the car was found abandoned in a nearby town with some other junk';

Object.keys(dict).forEach(function(d) {
  $.each(dict[d], function(i,v) {
    var searchWord = v.replace(/_/g, " ");
    var regEx = new RegExp("("+searchWord+")(?!([^<]+)?>)", "gi");

    var tmp = template.replace(regEx, "<span class='btn-group'><button class='btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle' type='button' data-toggle='dropdown'>"+searchWord+"<span class='caret'></span></button><ul id='"+i+"' class='dropdown-menu'></ul></span>");
    if (tmp !== template) {
      template = tmp;
      console.log(template);
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

The above will output:

```
"<span class='btn-group'><button class='btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle' type='button' data-toggle='dropdown'>the car was found abandoned in a nearby town<span class='caret'></span></button><ul id='0' class='dropdown-menu'></ul></span> with some other junk"
"<span class='btn-group'><button class='btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle' type='button' data-toggle='dropdown'>the car was found abandoned in a nearby town<span class='caret'></span></button><ul id='0' class='dropdown-menu'></ul></span> with <span class='btn-group'><button class='btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle' type='button' data-toggle='dropdown'>some other<span class='caret'></span></button><ul id='2' class='dropdown-menu'></ul></span> junk"
```

Another approach for that, that doesn't require pre-ordering the dictionary inputs, is to maintain a list of used inputs and checking that none of the remaining inputs are substrings of the ones already used, should have the same end effect:

```
var output = ['the_car_was_found_abandoned_in_a_nearby_town', 'found_abandoned'];
var template = 'the car was found abandoned in a nearby town';

var strings_used = [];

$.each(output, function(i,v){
  for (var itr = 0; itr < strings_used.length; ++itr) {
    if (strings_used[itr].idnexOf(v) !== -1) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  var searchWord = v.replace(/_/g, " ");
  var regEx = new RegExp("("+searchWord+")(?!([^<]+)?>)", "gi");

  var tmp = template.replace(regEx, "<span class='btn-group'><button class='btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle' type='button' data-toggle='dropdown'>"+searchWord+"<span class='caret'></span></button><ul id='"+i+"' class='dropdown-menu'></ul></span>");
  if (tmp !== template) {
    strings_used.push(v);
    template = tmp;
    console.log(template);
  }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm getting confused now and I'm not sure if it's because I don't understand what I'm asking or because you don't.

This needs to be fairly dynamic. I don't just want to stop after the first iteration, I want to stop once all matches have been completed, in the order that they are entered into the array, but with no overlap. So if the entire string is replaced by a tag, then any matches within that string are left alone. If there are multiple matches within a string, then all must be replaced.

Comment: The dictionary is stored on a database and will be altered frequently by a number of different people. Unfortunately I am not able to separate strings from substrings within the database.

Comment: The reason being that each string in the dictionary then contains a lower level with all corresponding strings (matches defined based upon my own criteria which needn't be discussed here), so it may be that one match contains the other and vice versa.

Comment: I added another approach that is essentially the second approach, which is what I think you want, but minus the need to pre-order the dictionaries.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for the slow response... internet troubles... I'll test now and get back to you!

Comment: Just tested and the second approach works perfectly! Thank you!!

Comment: It was actually the third answer which helped, though I realised that it is still insufficient for my requirements.